# How to trigger a change event only after all multiselect selections have been made

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, multi-select

I have a multiselect dropdown element with check boxes and a change function for that element in my javascript file.  But the change function is triggered every time a check box is clicked.  I would like the change function to be triggered only after the user exits the select dropdown or hits 'enter' so it only runs once if a user checks five boxes instead of running five times (immediately after each new box is checked).  How can I do this?  Here is my current code:

html element:

```
 <select id="vo_select_mobile_brands" multiple="multiple">
         <option>Select a country</option>
    </select>
```

javascript dynamic addition of checkbox options:

```
$el = $('#vo_select_mobile_brands');
$el.empty()
$.each(_vo_mobile_brand_ids_list, function(idx, mobile_brand_id) {
    $el.append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", mobile_brand_id).text(mobile_brand_id));
});
$el.multiselect('destroy')
$el.multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});
$el.multiselect()
```

javascript change function:

```
$('#vo_select_mobile_brands').change(function() {
    _vo_selected_mobile_brands = [];
    selected_objects = $("#vo_select_mobile_brands option:selected")
    for(var i = 0; i < selected_objects.length; i++){
        //do something with the selected items
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Which event to use for multiselect change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816755/javascript-which-event-to-use-for-multiselect-change)

Answer (score 4):

You can execute your js function on a button click with button `click event` like

```
$('#ButtonID').click(function() {
    _vo_selected_mobile_brands = [];
    selected_objects = $("#vo_select_mobile_brands option:selected")
    for(var i = 0; i < selected_objects.length; i++){
        //do something with the selected items
    }
});
```

So it will get fired only when user want to submit after selecting multiple values from dropdown.

**OR**

If you still need to execute it on change event of dropdown when 5 items are selected then you can get count of the selected values and fire the function if selected items are equal to 5

```
$('#vo_select_mobile_brands').change(function() {
    var count = $("#vo_select_mobile_brands :selected").length;
    if(count==5)
    alert(count);
});
```

See fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4zabsa9e/7/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a delay, so that if several changes are made within a short time, your code only executes after the last one:

```
var timer = null;
$('#vo_select_mobile_brands').change(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer); // cancel and restart timer
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        _vo_selected_mobile_brands = [];
        selected_objects = $("#vo_select_mobile_brands option:selected")
        for(var i = 0; i < selected_objects.length; i++){
            //do something with the selected items
        }
    }, 1000); // after one second of idle time
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So only trigger when the select looses focus/blur perhaps?:

```
$("#vo_select_mobile_brands").on('focusout blur',function(){
    //will return an array of the values for the selected options
    var myselectedvalues = $(this).val();
});
```

> The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element
>   inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in
>   that it supports detecting the loss of focus from parent elements (in
>   other words, it supports event bubbling).

IF you manually change values via script, you can trigger the event:

```
$("#vo_select_mobile_brands").trigger("focusout");
```

Comment: This is the kind of solution I would like.  The other solutions (like using a timer or adding another button to click when the user is done selecting options) are not ideal but might have to do.  I could not make the 'on focusout' solution work with the elements I am using.  The parent element lost focus as soon as the child checkbox element is clicked, and the check box element lost focus as soon as the user moved on to the next check box.  I need some element to remain in focus the whole time the user is selecting checkboxes, and then lose focus only when the dropdown is exited.

Comment: Consider using some custom event and trigger that when you want to.